# Nginx container as a proxy to another docker container localhost - 502 BAD gateway

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a container which runs its web app on `localhost:4000` i want to access it through `nginx` which is in another container. I have created a `docker network` and ran the following to bring them under same network `mynetwork`

`docker run --name myapp -p 8080:4000 -d --network mynewnetwork ubuntunet:1.9` --- myapp

`docker run --name nginx -p 80:80 -d --network mynewnetwork nginx` --- nginx

with the following `nginx.conf`

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    sendfile on;

    upstream docker-myapp {
        server myapp:4000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;    
        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://docker-myapp;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }

}
```

For some reason this is not working showing `502 bad gateway` when i access docker host ip, when we create a `docker network` it opens all ports between the containers that resides in the same network correct? if yes why my app is not running. 
Should i change `hosts` file in `myapp` container to have `docker ip` with `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`? or i am missing something in this. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your app running in a healthy state? Or, are you able to access your app from the host machine directly via the port you mapped?